# Minimum and maximum sequential values of a vector

Tags: r, vector, max, minimum

I need to find the minimum and the maximum values of a vector, but the minimum one needs to be positioned inside before the maximum one. So, given the vector:

```
v <- c (8,2,1,3,5,7,4)
```

the minimum value would be '1' (the 3rd element) and the maximum '7' (the sixth element). The maximum value would *not* be indeed '8' (the 1th element) because it occurs before the minimum '1' (the 3rd element).

I looked at the functions 'min' and 'max' (and their faster versions pmin and pmax), but apparently they are only able to find the highest minimum and maximum values, with no restrictions in place. The same for the range function.

Is there anyone that could help?

Comment: Note that `pmin` is not a "faster version" of `min` - it is a pairwise minimum for comparing vectors element-by-element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
range(v[which.min(v):length(v)])

[1] 1 7
```

Answer (score 3):

using `which.min` you get the index of the minimum.
This you can use to subset `v` up to the end of your vector.

```
min <- min(v)
max <- max(v[ which.min(v): length(v)])

c(min, max)
```

Comment: I guess this works but a bit dangerous to use min where there is a default function min

Comment: This gives `min` as the position of the minimum (i.e. 3) rather than the minimum itself (1).

Comment: woops, indeed, an inadvertent edit switched things up. Thanks,